# C++ on Mac: Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macos, visual-studio-code

I am used to Visual Studio Code for Python and Javascript. I work on a Mac machine, and I am learning C++, and I don't know if Visual Studio Code is a good choice, or if Visual Studio Community would be more suitable.

Thanks!

Comment: You can also try the excellent free Eclipse, which is industry standard, or NetBeans, which is also very good.

Answer (score 1):

Get visual studio community since you are learning.
It's a full IDE so it is easier to configure, better learning curve

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that there is no version for mac… :(

Comment: There is but you can not code c/c++, mostly .NET stuff like c#. and cross platform  web/mobile Applications

Comment: Ah, yes, you are in reason, I can download it, but no IDE for c++ in Mac… This is a no-go for me :( I suppose I will stick with VSCode, which is a really nice editor, although is a bit harder creating projects in c++…

Comment: try the excellent free Eclipse, which is industry standard, or NetBeans, which is also very good.